# Disable the delete option from Sharepoint list 2010

Tags: permissions, custom-list, delete

I have a custom list in SharePoint 2010, for which, the requirement is to disable the delete option.  Users should be able to add to the list but not delete.  Is there anything oob for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a custom permission level based on Contribute that does NOT have the Delete Items option selected.  Apply this permission level to the list for the desired users.

See this article for full details, http://mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1019, the screenshots are from 2007 but the premise is exactly the same in 2010.

Comment: Note: this also prevents users with this custom permission level from being able to rename items. Also, in an environment that uses Retention Policies, I found that whenever a user with this custom permission level edits an item, that item's Expiration Date column becomes empty (my assumption is that normally, on the expiration date the automatic deletion of the item is attributed to the last editor of the item).