# All the moderation status of a list item

Tags: sharepoint-server

I would like to get all the moderation status of a list item in a deleting event. I have enabled 'versioning'.

If the item approved once, the item should not be deleted, this is my requirement.

Comment: Have you considered declaring it as a record?

Answer (score 0):

In Item deleting event you can write code like this

```
SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;

string Status =item[item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("_ModerationStatus").Id] 

 if (Status == "Approved")
   {

    properties.Cancel = true;
    properties.ErrorMessage = "Cannot delete data";

  }
```

Comment: Hi Amit, it will trigger if the current status is 'Approved'. if the user edit the iten then it status will go to 'Pending' and this error won't appear. I need to get all the 'ModerationStatus' of a particular item.

Comment: Then use Item Updated event also so that whenever item is updated or updating you can get the Moderationstatus of that item also

Comment: In SP2013, `properties.Cancel` is obsolete. You can use `properties.Status` and set it with the `SPEventReceiverStatus` enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property on SPListItem called [HasPublishedVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.haspublishedversion.aspx)

> Gets a Boolean value that specifies whether a published version of the item exists.

That will probably be your best bet.

Here is a code snippet you could use inside your ItemDeleting event:

```
if (properties.ListItem.HasPublishedVersion)
{
    // don't allow delete
    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
    properties.ErrorMessage = "Cannot delete items with published versions";
}
```

With this code, I've used `properties.Status` instead of `properties.Cancel` because it is obsolete in SP2013. If you are using SP2010, then use `properties.Cancel`.

Originally I thought you could simply check the version number? If it is >= 1 then it has been approved at some point. Draft versions increment the minor portion while published versions increment the major portion. This could be a backup option.

For example:
Version 0.16 has never been published. 
Version 3.3 has been published 3 times.

If you want to check the version number, the [SPListItem.Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemversioncollection.aspx) property returns a collection of item versions. You can index the collection like this `var latestVersion = versionColl[0];` and check the number of the most recent version using the [VersionLabel property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemversion.versionlabel.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the values can be found in this  enum:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPModerationStatus

public enum SPModerationStatusType
{
   Approved,
   Denied,
   Pending,
   Draft,
   Scheduled,
}
```

[MSDN Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spmoderationstatustype.aspx)

As to preventing it from being deleted once it's approved, maybe using [permission levels](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27187/disable-the-delete-option-from-sharepoint-list-2010) are more suitable than implementing an event receiver ?

Answer (score 0):

By the way if you came here for the same reason I did: SharePoint Online updated the internal name of the approval status for REST api to OData__ModerationStatus ( was just _ModerationStatus in SP2013.