# Create a custom Listitem permission

Tags: 2013, permissions

I need to define (without coding) proper permission on a SP 2013 list, which denies to delete items created by another user. If this is not possible then deny the delete at all.
I'm familiar with the permissions but I didn't understand if it's possible to create a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own Permission Level. This option is available in site permission at root site.

There you can get option to add/edit/copy permission level. Select what permission you need and create permission level. In your scenario you can copy "Edit" permission level and then in that copied permission level, remove delete permissions.

Here is a technet article on same https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You can create custom permission levels. refer [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc263239.aspx)

To achieve your requirement follow below steps:

1. Break permissions of list from inheriting from parent.
2. Create a workflow, to remove all permissions
    Follow these steps:

   1.Create SharePoint Designer workflow.

   2.Add impersonation Step

   3.Select and add "Remove List Item Permissions" action

   4.Click on 'these permissions' link

   5.Click Add Select the permissions you want to remove then click browse, 
   and select all groups which you want to remove access on that item.

   6.Now Add another action "Add List Item Permissions"

   7.Click Add Select the permissions Edit/contribute permission's, then click browse, and select "User who created current item". Click Add, Click Ok.

   8.In workflow setting mark it to on Item create. Save and publish the workflow.

   9.Only creator(Author) of item will be able to edit the item.

Comment: What do you mean with point 2?

Comment: I have modified the answer in detailed steps

Comment: Well, i need the `delete`...where workflows don't start/work.

Comment: sorry, couldn't get your last comment

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom permission level based on Contribute that does NOT have the Delete Items option selected. Apply this permission level to the list for the desired users.

See this article for full details, http://mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1019, the screenshots are from 2007, but it would give you an idea on how to do it in 2013, the whole process is same but the look and feel will be slightly different in 2013.

You can also do you requirement using "List Event Handler", in that you can use the event "ItemDeleting" and restrict delete.

for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
namespace ItemDeletingEventHandler
{
    public class Class1 :SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPListItem Item = properties.ListItem;
            if (Item["Vendor Name"] != null)
            {
                if (Item["Vendor Name"].ToString() == "Ravish")
                {
                    //For canciling the delete operation
                    properties.Cancel = true;
                    //Show message to user
                    properties.ErrorMessage = "Can't Delete";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more information about programmatically achieving it, refer the below link,
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Ravish001/restrict-a-user-to-delete-from-a-sharepoint-list-using-item-deleting-event-handler/

[Source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27187/disable-the-delete-option-from-sharepoint-list-2010)

Comment: Well, i meant without coding...

Answer (score 0):

Use OOTB list setting where an user can edit only its own items. You can also make it 'Read'.